# MS Access SQL - Capture changes in status over time

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, jet-sql

I have an Access 2007 database that tracks document progression through time. The progression goes like:

1. Created
2. Sent for Review
3. Reviewed
4. Sent for Approval
5. Approved

I've created a history table for changes in document status with columns like this:

```
hist_id    doc_id    month   step    status  datestamp
```

I've created a query that returns statuses for the end of the month, like so:

```
SELECT doc_id, month, step, status, datestamp
FROM hist
WHERE (((hist.datestamp) In 
(
      Select Top 1 h.[datestamp]
      From hist as h
      Where h.[doc_id] = hist.[doc_id] and h.[month] = hist.[month]
      Order By h.[datestamp] DESC))
)
ORDER BY month, doc_id DESC;
```

to get....

```
doc_id  month   step status             datestamp
a       2011-01 2    sent for review    18/01/2011
b       2011-02 1    created            01/02/2011
a       2011-02 3    reviewed           19/02/2011
c       2011-03 1    created            07/03/2011
d       2011-03 1    created            08/03/2011
e       2011-06 1    created            14/06/2011
f       2011-07 1    created            05/07/2011
g       2011-07 4    sent for approval  18/07/2011
h       2011-07 2    sent for review    14/07/2011
f       2011-08 3    reviewed           29/08/2011
g       2011-08 5    approved           17/08/2011
h       2011-08 1    created            10/08/2011
e       2011-09 3    reviewed           17/09/2011
```

But what I really need is my query to also return documents in months for which the status hasn't changed. For example, document `a`'s status became `reviewed` on `19/02/2011`, but that's the last time it shows up in the results above. It should actually show up in every month afterward as `reviewed` until it later becomes `sent for approval`.

So I'm trying to modify my query (or query the above query) to provide results like below...

```
 doc_id month   step    status          datestamp
a   2011-01 2   sent for review     18/01/2011
a   2011-02 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-02 1   created         01/02/2011
a   2011-03 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-03 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-03 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-03 1   created         08/03/2011
a   2011-04 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-04 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-04 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-04 1   created         08/03/2011
a   2011-05 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-05 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-05 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-05 1   created         08/03/2011
a   2011-06 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-06 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-06 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-06 1   created         08/03/2011
e   2011-06 1   created         14/06/2011
a   2011-07 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-07 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-07 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-07 1   created         08/03/2011
e   2011-07 1   created         14/06/2011
f   2011-07 1   created         05/07/2011
g   2011-07 4   sent for appr   18/07/2011
h   2011-07 2   sent for rev    14/07/2011
a   2011-08 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-08 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-08 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-08 1   created         08/03/2011
e   2011-08 1   created         14/06/2011
f   2011-08 3   reviewed        29/08/2011
g   2011-08 5   approved        17/08/2011
h   2011-08 1   created         10/08/2011
a   2011-09 3   reviewed        19/02/2011
b   2011-09 1   created         01/02/2011
c   2011-09 1   created         07/03/2011
d   2011-09 1   created         08/03/2011
e   2011-09 1   reviewed        17/09/2011
f   2011-09 3   reviewed        29/08/2011
g   2011-09 5   approved        17/08/2011
h   2011-09 1   created         10/08/2011
```

Thanks for your help... I really don't even know where to start here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in SQL and doesn't use any special features, so should work in MS-ACCESS SQL as well.

First, you will need to create a table on months.

```
create table monthly (monthN char(7))

insert into monthly values('2011-01')
insert into monthly values('2011-02')
...
```

and populate it with all the months you need.

With that table built, the following query should return what you are looking for:

```
select d1.doc_id,d1.monthN,d1.step,d1.status,d1.dateStamp
from monthly m1
join docs d1 on d1.monthN=m1.monthN
union
select d2.doc_id,zz.monthN,d2.step,d2.status,d2.dateStamp
from docs d2
join
(
    select aa.doc_id,aa.monthN,bb.EndM from
    (
    select yy.doc_id,yy.monthN from
    (   
        select d3.doc_id,m2.monthN
        from monthly m2
        join (select distinct doc_id from docs) d3 on 1=1
        ) yy
    left join docs xx on xx.doc_id=yy.doc_id and xx.monthN=yy.MonthN
    where xx.hist_id is null
    ) aa
    join (select doc_id,MIN(monthN) as startM,MAX(monthN) as EndM 
          from docs group by doc_id) 
          bb on bb.doc_id=aa.doc_id and aa.monthN>=bb.StartM
) zz
on zz.doc_id=d2.doc_id and zz.EndM=d2.monthN
order by d1.monthN,d1.doc_id
```

I would suggest running each inner query separately to help follow what is being done...

Comment: Wow, thanks so much that! I haven't had a chance to try ityet, but I forgot to mention in my question that the statuses can go backwards i.e. `sent for approval` back to `reviewed` if it doesn't get approved. Do you know if your solution will accomodate that? i.e. not look for the highest status in a month, but the statuses with the highest dates in the month.

Comment: it should, it uses the most recent status if there is no record for the month.   If not, let me know and I'll take a ppek

Comment: It seems that the query isn't quite returning the desired output. The 1=1 part from yy doesn't work in MS Access. Is the intention to create a cross join? The sytax in MS Access is `select * from table1, table 2` so I've update to reflect. It still isn't working, and I spent some time trying to debug. I couldn't figure it out,  but with some clues from your answer(cross join, table for months), I was able to piece it together on my own from there. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some clues from Sparky's answer, I was able to piece together something that works for me.

Steps

1. Create a `months` table  to contain list of months like `2011-08`
2. Create a `month_range` query to get the range of months from actual documents

   SELECT month_no FROM months WHERE month BETWEEN (minium month for hist) AND (max month for hist)
3. Do a cross product query with `month_range` and `hist` tables, where `hist.month_no` <= `month_range.month`
4. The step above leaves a table with multiple status changes per month per document. Just GROUP BY on `month_no` and `doc_no` with `max(hist_id)` in the SELECT
5. INNER JOIN the result from above with the `hist` table using `hist_id` to get access to the status

The exact final query that I used looks like this....

```
SELECT xx.month_no, xx.swp, xx.hist_id, h.status

FROM 
(
     SELECT zz.month_no, zz.swp, Max(zz.hist_id) AS hist_id
     FROM 
     (
          SELECT * FROM month_range AS mr, hist AS h 
          WHERE h.[first_of_month] <= mr.[first_of_month]
     ) zz
     GROUP BY zz.month_no, zz.swp

)  xx 

INNER JOIN hist as h ON xx.hist_id = h.hist_id;
```